# Can symfony2 project be set up in a way that it would be ready to run from a folder in webserver root without clearing cache or any configuration?

Tags: symfony

I would like to have a `project.zip` file that can be unzipped, copied to a web server's root folder and just run without having to clear cache, set config, etc... The idea is that I want to create a piece of software that anyone can use by simply uploading the folder to their website. Let's assume for the sake of this argument that the end user would not be able to carry out common symfony2 configuration steps, including clearing cache, setting permissions, virtual host, etc..

So:

```
unzip project.zip

mv project /var/www/
```

and then http://localhost/project/ would be running a symfony project.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: you're gonna need to at least set write permissions on the cache folders in a secure way...

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because the Symfony cache still contains some absolute paths. But this is being fixed upstream, see for instance this PR https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/19687